# Wireshark TLS conversation for ldaps

Tags: ssl, wireshark, tcpdump

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue with delays in LDAPS bind operations with tcpdump/wireshark.

Here is what I get from client side on a conversation with delays:
[image]

I see the following problems:

1. I see no ServerHello response (this happens for all TLS sesssions). May be this a Wireshark or tcpdump collection issue?
2. There is a gap of 8 seconds between the "Client Hello" and the next ACK. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: There seems to be only one direction of conversation here. Only the client-to-server traffic is showing. Nothing is showing from server-to-client. Did something go wrong with your capture or was it filtered out?

Comment: You are right. I had set  "dst xx.xx.xx.xx" which hides the reply section of the session.

Comment: You should do a new capture, then, which contains both directions of the conversation. Consider a capture filter like `host 198.51.100.83 and port 636`